# Determine if viewer is following on twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-follow

I'm trying to determine whether the current viewer of my website is currently following my twitter account. If not I want to display a box in the bottom right which asks the user to follow me.

How do I check whether the user is following me or not?

I have looked at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids which says to use screen_name or user_id. however I do not know how to get this from someone who is viewing my site.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To check if the current user is following you or not, first you need to know his twitter id or screen name. Then you can check if he is following you or not.

check this documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friendships/lookup

If the current user follows you then there will be "followed_by" in connections array in sample response they given in the above link.

I wish this helps you

Note : you are checking in API version 1, it has been deprecated long ago, please upgrade to API version 1.1